# Jailbreak app - Play a background music during phone call

Tags: jailbreak, theos

I'm in the process of writing an jailbreak iPhone app  that will play a background music during the call.

Is there a way to play sounds or music in the background WHILE on a call so that the person can hear it too?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be a tweak? Trying hooking into the Music or Messages app. %hook whaterveryouwanthere
//Enter code here 
%end

Comment: Can you please elaborate?